# Calculating sequence loss for a sentence based language model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to write a dynamic rnn that takes variable length sentences as input. I'm getting a bit confused about how to calculate the cross-entropy loss.

Tensorflow methods like sequence_loss_by_example and sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits seem to take two arguments, the output logits of the network, and the targets labels.

I'm confused about the shape of these target labels. It seems that the dimensions of those two things should match. In my current implementation, my input would be, for instance, [word1, word2, word3, end-of-sentence-token]. I Can't seem to figure out what my target labels would look like, in this case. It seems like they would be identical, but in that case it would look like I'm just predicting the word I'm getting as an input. So that doesn't feel right. Anything obvious I'm missing here?

One more question: I have an unknown token for out-of-vocabulary words. Is it a problem to treat this token like any other word while calculating loss? Or should I somehow increase costs for predicting unknown words?

Comment: If I understand correctly, one of the ways to define the loss in the language model is to predict the next word, so your output would be [word2, word3]

Comment: Hrm, so the first word would not be predicted? And wouldn't the end of sentence token be predicted as well?

Comment: You can predict the first word, e.g. passing [START, word1, word2, word3] and predict the EOS token as well -- output would be [w1, w2, w3, EOS]

Comment: Ah yes, that's perfect. I'll take that approach. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Set a template of a bigger size and pad the remaining spaces with zeros or any special character for which you can later set the weights to be 0

Ex: [word1, word2, word3, end-of-sentence-token, PAD_word, PAD_word, PAD_word, PAD_word, ...., PAD_word]